# wp_update_post not working

Tags: wp-query, wp-update-post

I have the following code in a single script to be run one time to fix post names which are empty.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
        'post_type'              => 'books',
        'name'                                   => '',
        'post_status'            => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'                 => -1,
);
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_posts_where' );
echo "1";
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "2";
$germanizer = new Germanizer();
// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                // do something
                $seo_slug   = seo_slugs( $germanizer->sanitize_title_filter( $post->post_title ) );
                // check the slug and run an update if necessary
                if ( $post->post_name != $seo_slug ) {
                        wp_update_post(
                        array (
                                'ID'        => $post->ID,
                                'post_name' => $seo_slug
                        )
                        );
                }
        }
}

function custom_posts_where( $where ) {
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    if( FALSE === strpos( $where, 'post_name' ) ) {
        $where .= sprintf( " AND %s.post_name = '' ", $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts );
    }
    return $where;
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I have included `wp-config.php` so that is not the problem. In fact the script executes without any error on my local development environment (MAMP) and prints `2` but does not update the `post_name`.

But on my test env, it echoes only `1` without any error and it naturally does not update the `post_name`. The total number of posts on my test env is around 5k, so I wonder if that is the reason.

This code uses [Germanix Plugin](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin) by @toscho and might be relevant information.

Comment: Are you using [the "Germanizer" plugin](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php)?

Comment: Yes @kaiser I am using toscho's Germanizer plugin.

Comment: That's some pretty relevant information (like any plugin). Please [edit] your question and add a link to the plugins repository.

Comment: Turn on WP_DEBUG. What do you get then?

Comment: Finally I was able to find out that it was failing due to exhausted memory. 

I fixed it by limiting the number of posts to 500 and executing the script every minute using crontab

Moderators can delete this question. This was simple and I am sorry for wasting all your time.